# Como detener una consulta cuando los resultados son iguales

Tags: c#, sql-server

De antemano, disculpen el titulo o pregunta, realmente no se como nombrarla, pero bien.

Tengo un metodo o procedimiento almacenado que me devuelve como resultado el proveedor al cual se le han realizado mas compras. El metodo funciona correctamente, pero ahora que ando probando mi sistema, llegue a un punto donde solo tengo 2 compras de distintos proveedores, lo que hace mi metodo es que me devuelve el nombre del proveedor que figura en la compra mas reciente puesto que tiene un ORDER BY DESC. Lo que quiero saber es, si es posible validar dentro del metodo para que cuando los resultados sean iguales, es decir, aunque hayan 20 compras pero sean a 20 proveedores distintos, teóricamente no existe un proveedor con mas compras que otro, ya que todos figurarían solo dentro de una compra, entonces, que me muestre un resultado por default o simplemente no retorne nada y ya dentro de mi aplicación yo valido si la consulta arroja filas.

Este es mi metodo o procedimiento almacenado

```
select TOP 1 proveedor.Nombre as Proveedor, count(cabeza.IDCompra) AS cantidadp
from Tab_comprascabeza as cabeza 
INNER JOIN Tab_comprasdetalles as detalles on cabeza.IDCompra=detalles.IDCompra
INNER JOIN Tab_proveedores as proveedor ON cabeza.ID=proveedor.ID
WHERE
detalles.fecha between  DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
group by proveedor.Nombre
ORDER BY cantidadp DESC
```

Gracias de antemano,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre puedes anexar otro conjunto y devolver el mayor.

```
Select top(1) d.proveedor, d.cantidadp
from (
    Select 
        Top (1) proveedor.nombre As proveedor
              , Count(cabeza.idcompra) As cantidadp
              , 1 as t
        From tab_comprascabeza As cabeza
            Inner Join tab_comprasdetalles As detalles On cabeza.idcompra = detalles.idcompra
            Inner Join tab_proveedores As proveedor On cabeza.id = proveedor.id
       Where detalles.fecha Between DateAdd(day, -30, GetDate()) And GetDate()
       Group By proveedor.nombre
    union all
    Select '' as proveedor , 
            0 as cantidadp ,
            0 as t
    ) as d

Order By d.t desc, d.cantidadp Desc;
```

De manera que tu query, queda encerrada en una tabla derivada a la cual le anexamos lo que tienes, más una columna que nos servirá para la salida de la misma, saber si tiene filas.

Al mismo le unimos otro conjunto con los valores por defecto, que esperes en c#. Puedes hacer un Select null as proveedor, ya que regresará a un string y por tanto en lenguaje cliente puedes ya compararlo con un String.IsNullOrEmpty(myReader["proveedor"]).

Y la tabla derivada, siempre retornará un valor, ya que recuperamos mediante el operador top 1 sola fila, por la columna anexada a los conjuntos, aunque esa no se devuelve.

[Tablas derivadas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/06/tabla-derivada/)

Answer (score 0):

Primero hay que definir bien que se quiere. Si varios tienen las mismas compras, tal vez se deberían regresar todos ellos. La opción `TOP` puede regresar empates sin problemas usando solo usando la opción `WITH TIES`.

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES 
    proveedor.Nombre as Proveedor, 
    count(cabeza.IDCompra) AS cantidadp
FROM       Tab_comprascabeza   AS cabeza 
INNER JOIN Tab_comprasdetalles AS detalles  ON cabeza.IDCompra = detalles.IDCompra
INNER JOIN Tab_proveedores     AS proveedor ON cabeza.ID       = proveedor.ID
WHERE
    detalles.fecha BETWEEN  DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY proveedor.Nombre
ORDER BY cantidadp DESC;
```

Ahora, sí lo que quieres es realmente mostrar únicamente cuando solo haya un proveedor con más compras que el resto. Entonces solo necesitamos validar que solo haya un proveedor en la consulta anterior. Estoy usando un CTE, ya que me parece más ordenado y tiene mayor versatilidad que una tabla derivada.

```
WITH cteCompras AS(
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES 
        proveedor.Nombre as Proveedor, 
        count(cabeza.IDCompra) AS cantidadp
    FROM       Tab_comprascabeza   AS cabeza 
    INNER JOIN Tab_comprasdetalles AS detalles  ON cabeza.IDCompra = detalles.IDCompra
    INNER JOIN Tab_proveedores     AS proveedor ON cabeza.ID       = proveedor.ID
    WHERE
        detalles.fecha BETWEEN  DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    GROUP BY proveedor.Nombre
    ORDER BY cantidadp DESC
)
SELECT MAX(Proveedor) AS Proveedor, --Para que funcione el COUNT necesitamos agrupar a los proveedores.
       cantidadp
FROM cteCompras
GROUP BY cantidadp
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```